# rails helpers string interpolation in erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, link-to, ruby-on-rails-7

I am using the ternary operator for single-line conditions, with erb printing tag <%=  %>

```
<p>Status:
     <%= notification.read? ? "Read" : link_to "Mark as Read", "/" %>
</p>
```

I need to give a mark as read link in false condition, in the above scenario getting the syntax template error, here notification is an object of the Notification model.

I want output as-

```
mark as read
```

mark as read would be link.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a ternary:

```
<% if notification.read? %>
  Read
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Mark as Read', '/' %>
<% end %>
```

Or use parentheses in the `link_to` method call:

```
<%= notification.read? ? 'Read' : link_to('Mark as Read', '/') %>
```

Remember that anything inside `<%= ... %>` is just Ruby and that `link_to` is just a Ruby method like any other.